# Is there another step needed to enable memcache in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, memcached

memcache is installed on my vps environment

i have addd the necessary coding in file app/etc/local.xml

Should i not enable his function somewhere in Magento admin panel too?

Edit:

as requested:

```
<cache>
    <backend>memcached</backend>
    <memcached>
        <servers>
            <server>
                <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
                <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
            </server>
        </servers>
        <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
        <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
        <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
        <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
        <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
    </memcached>
</cache>
```

According to the hosting company memcached is configured correct on server en also in xml file... they told me that magento doesn't seem to address the cache and that i needed to find a setting in backend to enable it... propably they dont know what they are talking about?

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you would actually post _what_ you have "coded" for this in your app/etc/local.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you just need to configure it in app/etc/local.xml and then check the performance change. Or you can check it by type this command line

```
echo "stats cachedump 15 4" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
```

I think you know how to use this kind of command. If it is working well then you should see a lot of data.

Comment: where would i need to type this command Phuc?

Comment: You can type it in any command line tool. For example: you can login to SSH server via putty and type this command. Or command prompt in windows, terminal in MacOSX

Answer (score 1):

If you have access via SSH, try doing

```
telnet localhost 11211
stats
```

and you should see some stats about the service.